# Import raster data from PostGIS and publish in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, boundless-suite

I am using GeoServer 2.3.3, PostGIS 2.1 and PostgreSQl 9.1.  The Image Mosaic JDBC extension is also installed correctly.

I am trying to import raster data from PostGIS and publish in GeoServer but facing an error.I followed the following tutorial.

I have imported the raster to PostGIS using raster2pgsql, the command I used is:

**raster2pgsql -M -I -C -e -Y -F -s 4326 -t 128x128  -l 2,4 geo_liss.tif public.raster_table | psql -U postgres -d postgis_test -h localhost -p 5433**

I have even verified whether the image is imported into database correctly or not, by downloading it using gdal_translate.

http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html

These are my XML configuration files...

**rasterdata.pgraster.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
  <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.pgraster.xml.inc">
  <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.pgraster.xml.inc">
 ]>

 <config version="1.0">
  <coverageName name="oek"/>
  <coordsys name="EPSG:4326"/>
  <!-- interpolation 1 = nearest neighbour, 2 = bipolar, 3 = bicubic -->
  <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
<axisOrder ignore="false"/>
  &mapping;
  &connect;
</config>
```

**connect.pgraster.xml.inc**

```
 <connect>
 <dstype value="DBCP"/>
 <username value="postgres"/>
 <password value="postgres"/>
 <jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/geo"/>
 <driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
 <maxActive value="10"/>
 <maxIdle value="0"/>
 </connect>
```

**mapping.pgraster.xml.inc**

```
  <spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
  <mapping>
  <masterTable name="mosaic" >
          <coverageNameAttribute name="name"/>
          <maxXAttribute name="maxx"/>
          <maxYAttribute name="maxy"/>
          <minXAttribute name="minx"/>
          <minYAttribute name="miny"/>
          <resXAttribute name="resx"/>
          <resYAttribute name="resy"/>
          <tileTableNameAtribute  name="tiletable" />
  </masterTable>
  <tileTable>
      <blobAttributeName name="rast" />
  </tileTable>
  </mapping>
```

I have stored these XML configuration files in the GeoServer data directory under the coverages folder.

When I try to use the image mosaic JDBC plugin to import the raster data through JDBC database, it gives an error, i.e.  **"Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Argument "value" should not be null."**

I have imported the raster data by giving the path of oek.pgrasterlxml in the URL required

As it doesn't work, I tried to import data in PostGIS database using import data in GeoServer. I have provided the SRS also. The data is imported correctly, but when I view it using OpenLayers I am unable to view, instead the WMS is providing an exception report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> 
  <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >
      <ServiceException>
  illegal bbox, minX: 0.0 is greater than maxX: -1.0
      </ServiceException>
  </ServiceExceptionReport>
```